# Как сохранить данные в приложении android?

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать загрузку из интернета изображений и аудиофайлов и сохранение их в устройстве? Что использовать, может какие-то бибилиотеки или есть готовые примеры?

Comment: Всем спасибо за развернутые и подробные ответы!

Comment: Попробуйте [эти либы](https://github.com/search?l=Java&o=desc&q=android+download&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=✓) из гитхаб